# A better tool for reading law than congress.gov

Tags: united-states, congress, bills

I am looking at the [Bipartisan Budget Act of 2019](https://www.congress.gov/bill/116th-congress/house-bill/3877/text), and interested in discovering how much spending the budget covers.

Early in the bill, there is a reference to existing legislation: "--Section 251(c) of the Balanced Budget and Emergency Deficit Control Act of 1985 (2 U.S.C. 901(c)) is amended by striking paragraphs (7) and (8) and inserting the following: ...", but the amended bill is not linked anywhere and [my search](https://www.congress.gov/search?q=%7B%22source%22:%22legislation%22,%22search%22:%22%5C%22Balanced%20Budget%20and%20Emergency%20Deficit%20Control%20Act%20of%201985%5C%22%22%7D&searchResultViewType=expanded&KWICView=false) failed to turn anything up.

What tools do people usually use for reading legislation? I am thinking about trying to build one if this is as good as it gets, but I expect I am just looking in the wrong place.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a question about the law but a question about research materials.

Comment: I'm happy to move this or close it, if you have any idea where it belongs. I figured that legal research was a part of the practice of law, and that people that work closely with law would have a recommendation of where to find relevant legislation.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch I always thought that legal research questions were on topic.

Comment: I think that the material you are looking for is on Congress.gov but it can be a bit hard to work thought to find.

Answer (score 2):

There a few places; this particular statute, for example, can be found [on Cornell's legal site](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/2/901) or on [that of the House](https://legcounsel.house.gov/Comps/Balanced%20Budget%20And%20Emergency%20Deficit%20Control%20Act%20Of%201985--(Part%20C).pdf).

Answer (score 1):

[uslaw.link](https://uslaw.link) is the best tool I've found so far for looking up citations. Cornell's legal site @Jack Fleeting linked is the best free site I've found so far. It has some references to other documents linked and tries to give definitions to some terms used in the text.

From asking around a bit, it sounds like legal professionals use [WestLaw](https://legal.thomsonreuters.com/en/products/westlaw) or [Lexis](https://legal.thomsonreuters.com/en/products/westlaw). I'm not aware of better tools for reading law as a layperson.